# Remove special character from a string in java only regex pattern ex 1'563 I need it like 1563 not using string.replace

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string: `String= 1'563` . I need it like `1563`

Currently, my regex pattern looks like this: `[\\d+,\\.]`

I'd like to remove characters such as `'`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using replace function?

Comment: Your regex pattern for what? How are you using it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to replace anything which is not a digit (`\D`) with the empty string:

```
    String resultString = "1'563".replaceAll("\\D", "");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1563
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to keep the dot:

```
    String resultString = "1'563.3".replaceAll("[^\\d|\\.]", "");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1563.3
```

Comment: The OP says, *not using string.replace*.

Comment: @R.J I think that he meant that he doesn't want stuff like `"1'563".replaceAll("'","")` - he wanted to know how to do it using a regex (to remove **any** non-digit character) in order to "clean" the string and leave only digits.

Comment: Shouldn't this read "anything which is not a *digit*" ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt right - thanks! (corrected)

Comment: @alfasin, Don't you think this will remove `.` as well?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya updated the answer for non-integer numbers as well

Comment: @All, I don't want to use .replace all. I just need the pattern like [\\S./]+\\d

Comment: @BharathAradhya and how do you plan on using that regex to "clean" the string ? what method you're going to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using replace function

```
String original= "1'563";
String arr [] =  original.split("';-|\\."); \\ specify regex of characters to remove
String ans = "";

for(String temp : arr)
    ans+=temp;
```

**EDIT :**
Either use   `original.split("[^\\d|\\.]");`

Comment: read the question again: `'` was just an example - the OP wants to get rid of **any** "special" character (probably means "non-digit")

Comment: What happens when there are multiple characters like *+*, *,* etc..?!

Comment: @alfasin, you can specify multiple characters for spliting

Comment: @AlpeshGediya right but you didn't show the OP how to do it...

Comment: @alfasin, will update my answer ..:)

Comment: @All, I don't want to use .replace all. I just need the pattern like [\\S./]+\\d with the special character removed

Comment: @AlpeshGediya will u plz help.

Comment: @BharathAradhya, use  `string.".split("\\D+", "");` instead of
` original.split("';-|\\."); ` in above code